# Bxslider border issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, bxslider

Trying to properly align the bxslider border so that it fits my images.

I've tried with many number of different images, with the bxslider at different setttings.

The Bxslider will in fact fit the images if I remove the options "Mode:'Fade" and "Captions:"True" and whilst I can live without the captions, I would indeed like to have the fade transition.

You can see what I mean here http://www.dennysplace.co.uk/

This is also a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FLuRH/

Code as follows

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/barbers1.jpg" title="Dennys Place Gentlemens Barbers"></li>
  <li><img src="images/display.jpg" title="Tunbridge Wells"></li>
  <li><img src="images/photos11.jpg" title="The famous heads of Dennys Place"></li>
 </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions:true,
    auto: true

});
 });
</script>
```

And CSS here

```
.bx-wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 0 0 60px;
padding: 0;
*zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
border: solid #fff 5px;
left: -5px;
background: #fff;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
position: absolute;
bottom: -30px;
width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
min-height: 50px;
background: url(images/bx_loader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
text-align: center;
font-size: .85em;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
color: #666;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
background: #666;
text-indent: -9999px;
display: block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin: 0 5px;
outline: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
left: 10px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
right: 10px;
background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover {
background-position: -43px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -16px;
outline: 0;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
text-indent: -9999px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 10px;
height: 11px;
outline: 0;
background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
display: block;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 9px;
height: 11px;
outline: 0;
background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
text-align: left;
width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
right: 0;
width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: #666\9;
background: rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.75);
width: 100%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
color: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
display: block;
font-size: .85em;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Move your css includes into `head` section, `link` element is not allowed inside body tag.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't make any visible difference.

Comment: Do you want your images to be centered inside `bx-slider` div or fit?

Comment: I'd like them to fit the margin in the same proportions on all sides. Doesn't have to be centered, just fit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding this to your css should do it :

```
ul.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I also just changed the content tags from <ul> to <div> and for some reason it fixed the border issue. I'll run yours too and see what gives me a better positioning. Thanks!

Comment: Note:  CSS should always be implemented in an external CSS stylesheet, not the body of your document, as informed in bxslider [site](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2)